# Anylogic NullPointer Exception Process Modeling Blocks

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I have created a very simple model in AnyLogic consisting of source, Service, sink and resourcepool blocks. The source is connected to service which is then connected to sink. The source block generates agents of type 1 and resourcepool has agent type 2. When I run the model, I am getting following runtime error. There are no attributes to both the agent types. Also, agent types are created and not population.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.anylogic.engine.Port.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Seize.doCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.createAsEmbedded(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Service.doCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.createAsEmbedded(Unknown Source)
at model.Main.doCreate(Main.java.619)
at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.createAsEmbedded(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.create(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
```

I tried debugging the model but no success and also verified that all the initializations are not null.

Model:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSkgT.png)

Source properties:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOKPs.png)

Service properties:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqHs8.png)

Resourcepool properties:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0lO7.png)

Comment: add a picture of your process, and a picture of the properties of your service and resourcepool blocks... otherwise difficult to know the problem

Comment: added pictures of model and block properties

Comment: maybe you didn't really connect the connectors correct? Try delete them all and redo carefully

Comment: Reconnected the blocks. Still facing the same issue.
Any possibility that any of the agents is null?

Comment: very mysterious problem.. can you upload this same model somewhere?